# How to serialize a form with an array of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm trying to serialize a form that can contains an array of object and send it to my application service and i cannot find any way to make it work...

Here is my Save Method

```
var brewer = _$form.serializeFormToObject();

abp.services.app.brewer.create(brewer).done(() => {
    ...
});

// brewerService
serviceNamespace.create = function(brewerDto, ajaxParams) {
    return abp.ajax($.extend({
        url: abp.appPath + 'api/services/app/brewer/Create',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(brewerDto)
    }, ajaxParams));
};
```

Here is my form

```
<form name="AddBrewerForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-validation">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-nav-right" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#brewer-detail" data-toggle="tab">@L("BrewerDetails")</a>
        </li>

        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#beers-list" data-toggle="tab">@L("Beers")</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane animated fadeIn active" id="brewer-detail">
            <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group form-float">
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" required class="validate form-control" />
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane animated fadeIn" id="beers-list">
            <div id="beer-list-content">
                <div class="brewer-beer-card row form-group form-float" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input id="beer-0" type="text" name="Beers[0].Name" required class="validate form-control" />
                            <label for="beer-0" class="dynamic-beer-label form-label">@L("Name")</label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="brewer-beer-card row form-group form-float" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input id="beer-1" type="text" name="Beers[1].Name" required class="validate form-control" />
                            <label for="beer-1" class="dynamic-beer-label form-label">@L("Name")</label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                    <button type="button" id="add-beer-button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect">
                        @L("Add")
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

ApplicationServiceDto

```
public class InsertBrewerDto
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<NewBrewerBeerDto> Beers { get; set; }
}

public class NewBrewerBeerDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

jquery plugin of ABP for serialization

```
$.fn.serializeFormToObject = function () {
    //serialize to array
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();

    //add also disabled items
    $(':disabled[name]', this).each(function () {
        data.push({ name: this.name, value: $(this).val() });
    });

    //map to object
    var obj = {};
    data.map(function (x) { obj[x.name] = x.value; });

    return obj;
};
```

I Keep receiving null for my arrays of Beers...

So I've tried to use the  $(form).serialize() but i'm getting this error: Your request is not valid!

### The following errors were detected during validation.

So there is no error shown...

Here is the Log file 
WARN  2017-09-30 10:53:13,458 [31   ] nHandling.AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute - Method arguments are not valid! See ValidationErrors for details.
Abp.Runtime.Validation.AbpValidationException: Method arguments are not valid! See ValidationErrors for details.
   at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.MethodInvocationValidator.ThrowValidationError()
   at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.MethodInvocationValidator.Validate()
   at Abp.WebApi.Validation.AbpApiValidationFilter.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.WebApi.Auditing.AbpApiAuditFilter.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.WebApi.Security.AntiForgery.AbpAntiForgeryApiFilter.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.WebApi.Authorization.AbpApiAuthorizeFilter.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
WARN  2017-09-30 10:53:13,458 [31   ] nHandling.AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute - There are 1 validation errors:
WARN  2017-09-30 10:53:13,458 [31   ] nHandling.AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute -  (brewerDto)

Javscript Console Error:

{code: 0, message: "Your request is not valid!", details: "The following errors were detected during validation.
↵ - 
↵", validationErrors: Array(1)}
code
:
0
details
:
"The following errors were detected during validation.
↵ - 
↵"
message
:
"Your request is not valid!"
validationErrors
:
Array(1)
0
:
members
:
Array(1)
0
:
"brewerDto"
length
:
1
message
:
""

**EDIT1**

JS for getting console

```
    var b1 = _$form.serialize();
    var b2 = _$form.serializeArray();
    var b3 = _$form.serializeFormToObject();

    console.log(b1);
    console.log(b2);
    console.log(b3);
```

b1

```
Name=123&Beers%5B0%5D.Name=123&Beers%5B1%5D.Name=321
```

b2

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:{name: "Name", value: "123"}
1:{name: "Beers[0].Name", value: "123"}
2:{name: "Beers[1].Name", value: "321"}
length:3
```

b3

```
{Name: "123", Beers[0].Name: "123", Beers[1].Name: "321"}
Beers[0].Name :"123"
Beers[1].Name : "321"
Name : "123"
```

Comment: try using `$('form').serialize()` and removing `JSON.stringify()`. Like this: `data: $('form').serialize()`

Comment: The same error is happening

Comment: see my Edit1 for console output

Comment: This worked for me, im thinking this might be a "Feature" of the abp framework. Might be worth a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.fn.serializeFormToObjectWithArraysOfObjects = function () {
    var obj = $(this).serializeFormToObject();
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var result = key.match(/(.*)\[(\d)\].(.*)/);
        if (result) {
          var outer = result[1];
          var index = result[2];
          var inner = result[3];
          obj[outer] = obj[outer] || [];
          obj[outer][index] = obj[outer][index] || {};
          obj[outer][index][inner] = obj[key];
          delete obj[key];
        }
      }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Output:

```
{Name: "123", Beers: [{Name: "123"}, {Name: "321"}]}
```

Comment: i think this should be a very good answer! but ABP still fail.... without any validation message waiting on their github page to see what is wrong

Comment: wow... stackoverflow made me check the wrong answer. sorry  github link https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2553

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using JSON and iterating over the form inputs manually?

There are many ways to serialise forms into a JSON Object, and they depend on the actual markup and the form names, this example relies on the "id" parameter to be set(and as best practise, make them **equal** to the field name:

```
<input name="example" id="example" />
```

There are other strategies, but I like this one because we can be *explicit* about what we want to send to the server:

```
var list_of_fields = ["f1","f2","f3"];
```

and we can apply simple validation rules here before sending them.

Some example code:

```
var list_of_fields = ["f1","f2","f3"];
var serialised_values = {}
for(var i=0;i<list_of_fields.length;i++){
    var dom_object = document.getElementById(list_of_fields[i]);
    if(dom_object.tagName == "INPUT" || dom_object.tagName == "TEXTAREA"){
        serialized_values[dom_object.name] = dom_object.value;
    }
    if(dom_object.tagName == "SELECT"){
        serialized_values[dom_object.name] = dom_object.options[dom_object.selectedIndex].value;
    }

    //other field types go here

    //validation can go here too...
}
console.log(serialized_values);
```

Comment: the Object are serialized by default... their property are serializable. For the Json i've tried Serialize and SerializeToArray and both doesnt work and i'm getting the error

Comment: what about converting $(this) to a reference to the actual form using a dom method, maybe the "this" thing is not the "this" you expect it to be??

Comment: this is definitly my form i confirm it

Comment: I edited my answer to explain my point further, please review, vince

Comment: My problem is that i have a List of the same item Beer[0].Name Beer[1].Name so the is going to be the same for all if i use this strategy or with an index. i would like something more generic that will create the json object because i dont know how many of each object i will have.

Comment: then I guess simply use document.getElementById("form").querySelector("INPUT") to get the list of items, no?